# Python categorize data in excel based on key words from another excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two excel sheets, one has four different types of categories with keywords listed. I am using Python to find the keywords in the review data and match them to a category. I have tried using pandas and data frames to compare but I get errors like "DataFrame objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed". I'm not sure if there is a better way but I am new to Pandas.

Here is an example:

Category sheet

| Service | Experience |
| --- | --- |
| fast | bad |
| slow | easy |

Data Sheet

| Review # | Location | Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New York | "The service was fast! |
| 2 | Texas | "Overall it was a bad experience for me" |

For the examples above I would expect the following as a result.
I would expect review 1 to match the category Service because of the word "fast" and I would expect review 2 to match category Experience because of the word "bad". I do not expect the review to match every word in the category sheet, and it is fine if one review belongs to more than one category.

Here is my code, note I am using a simple example. In the example below I am trying to find the review data that would match the Customer Service list of keywords.

```
import pandas as pd

# List of Categories
cat = pd.read_excel("Categories_List.xlsx")
# Data being used
data = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")

# Data Frame for review column
reviews = pd.DataFrame(data["reviews"])

# Data Frame for Categories
cs = pd.DataFrame(cat["Customer Service"])
be = pd.DataFrame(cat["Billing Experience"])
net = pd.DataFrame(cat["Network"])
out = pd.DataFrame(cat["Outcome"])

for i in reviews:
    if cs in reviews:
        print("True")
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build a regular expression from the `cat` frame:

```
exp = '|'.join([rf'(?P<{col}>{"|".join(cat[col].dropna())})' for col in cat])
```

```
(?P<Service>fast|slow)|(?P<Experience>bad|easy)
```

Alternatively replace `cat` with a list of columns to test:

```
cols = ['Service']
exp = '|'.join([rf'(?P<{col}>{"|".join(cat[col].dropna())})' for col in cols])
```

```
(?P<Service>fast|slow|quick)
```

---

Then to get matches use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas-series-str-extractall) and [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) into summary + [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) to add back to the `reviews` frame:

Aggregated into List:

```
reviews = reviews.join(
    reviews['Review'].str.extractall(exp).groupby(level=0).agg(
        lambda g: list(g.dropna()))
)
```

```
   Review #  Location                                  Review Service Experience
0         1  New York          The service was fast and easy!  [fast]     [easy]
1         2     Texas  Overall it was a bad experience for me      []      [bad]
```

Aggregated into String:

```
reviews = reviews.join(
    reviews['Review'].str.extractall(exp).groupby(level=0).agg(
        lambda g: ', '.join(g.dropna()))
)
```

```
   Review #  Location                                  Review Service Experience
0         1  New York          The service was fast and easy!    fast       easy
1         2     Texas  Overall it was a bad experience for me                bad
```

---

Alternatively for an existence test use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas-dataframe-any) on level=0:

```
reviews = reviews.join(
    reviews['Review'].str.extractall(exp).any(level=0)
)
```

```
   Review #  Location                                  Review  Service  Experience
0         1  New York          The service was fast and easy!     True        True
1         2     Texas  Overall it was a bad experience for me    False        True
```

Or iteratively over the columns and with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains):

```
cols = cat.columns
for col in cols:
    reviews[col] = reviews['Review'].str.contains('|'.join(cat[col].dropna()))
```

```
   Review #  Location                                  Review  Service  Experience
0         1  New York          The service was fast and easy!     True        True
1         2     Texas  Overall it was a bad experience for me    False        True
```